Accessing Tableau view via a Google apps script
I am trying to connect to Tableau from a Google Apps Script so that I can get the view data and populate a Google Sheet. Not finding any good examples online however.
I am using this code to connect via a Personal Access Token but I do not know how to parse the auth token which is returned in XML (despite me setting the content type as JSON) and then how to make a second call to query the server?
function tableauAPI() {
const options = {
 method: 'post',
 muteHttpExceptions: true,
 contentType: 'application/json',
 accept: 'application/json',
 payload: JSON.stringify(
   {
     credentials: {
       personalAccessTokenName: 'TestToken',
       personalAccessTokenSecret: '11122223333444455555',
       site: {
         contentUrl: '',
       },
     },
   }
 ),
};
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
 'https://example.tableau.com/api/3.21/auth/signin',
 options
);
console.log(response.getContentText());
}


Answer to question 1
About your 1st question I do not know how to parse the auth token which is returned in XML (despite me setting the content type as JSON), please include "Accept" in the request header. So, when your script is modified, please modify as follows.
Modified script:
function tableauAPI() {
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }, // Modified
    payload: JSON.stringify(
      {
        credentials: {
          personalAccessTokenName: 'TestToken',
          personalAccessTokenSecret: '11122223333444455555',
          site: {
            contentUrl: '',
          },
        },
      }
    ),
  };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://example.tableau.com/api/3.21/auth/signin', options);
  console.log(response.getContentText());
}

Answer to question 2
About your 2nd question how to make a second call to query the server, I cannot understand the method of the API you want to use. So, the following sample script is for using a GET method with the retrieved token. So, please modify this for your actual situation.
Sample script:
function tableauAPI() {
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }, // Modified
    payload: JSON.stringify(
      {
        credentials: {
          personalAccessTokenName: 'TestToken',
          personalAccessTokenSecret: '11122223333444455555',
          site: {
            contentUrl: '',
          },
        },
      }
    ),
  };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://example.tableau.com/api/3.21/auth/signin', options);
  const text = response.getContentText();
  console.log(text);
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(text);
    const token = obj.credentials.token;

    // If it's GET method,
    const url = "###"; // Please set your expected URL.
    const options = { headers: { "X-Tableau-Auth": token } }; // Here, the token is used in the request header.
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    console.log(res.getContentText())

  }
}

References:

fetch(url, params)
Signing In and Signing Out (Authentication)


Thank you so much, that worked perfectly.

@Gary Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
